# Test whether Path.relativize() would succeed?

Tags: java, nio

The method [`java.nio.file.Path.relativize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-) will throw `IllegalArgumentException` with some arguments.

> A relative path cannot be constructed if only one of the paths have a root component. Where both paths have a root component then it is implementation dependent if a relative path can be constructed.

For example, on Windows, the method can fail if the two arguments refer to paths on different drives.

Is there an OS-neutral way to test whether a particular argument is legal, *before* calling `Path.relativize()`, to avoid relying on an exception to handle a non-exceptional case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says it is *"implementation dependent"*, so no, but making some assumptions, you can check if they share the same root and file system.

[`getRoot()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getRoot--) returns null if the path has no root component, otherwise `/` for Linux-like OS's and e.g. `C:\` for Windows. If the other path has a different root (e.g. `D:\`), then `relativize()` will fail.

So, if both [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) objects are for the same [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html), and both are either relative (`getRoot()` returns null), or both have the same root component, `relativize()` should work fine.

Not perfect solution, since we don't know what the *"implementation"* thinks, but close enough?